# Same miner detection by Kaspersky Anti-Virus after every boot up

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware

I recently bought and downloaded Kaspersky. Since I downloaded it, after every reboot, it keeps detecting what seems to be a crypto miner. Every time it claims to delete it.
Should I be worried ?
`Name:not-a-virus:HEUR:RiskTool.Win64.Miner.gen`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but doesn't seem like your screenshots show anything but Windows components.  Is Kaspersky detecting a miner in those??  As for a miner being installed, it's very possible.  Some anti-virus programs even install their own miner (usually you have to choose the "feature") and they share revenue with you.

Comment: @pcalkins it claims that the search application and the error reporter are "Legitimate software that can be used by intruders to damage your computer or personal data." 
I don't think that a reputable anti-virus will do that

Comment: I see that, but where does it say this is a crypto miner?

Comment: @pcalkins in the name the miner.gen, I assumed this is a miner of some sort

Comment: I think they mean a general data-miner, not a crypto miner.  (btw, lots of websites already mine using your browser's built in web assembly)  Microsoft definitely mines your data.  You can read their privacy policies at Microsoft's site for various versions of Windows.  There are also ways to turn of file-indexing or error reporting, but probably not all the mining that Windows does.

Comment: @pcalkins could this be possibly malware that gets deleted but the core is still there so every boot it reinstalls the miner ?

Comment: Looks like Windows components to me. Right-click on each and choose "Properties", select "Digital Signatures" tab and then click "Details". It'll check the hash against the signature and then show you the signer. (should be Microsoft)  The one file I'm not so sure about is "XR.exe".  That might be worth a second or third look. (google search had a result about a coin miner)  If the signature isn't Microsoft or a company you trust, I would try deleting in Safe Mode.

Comment: If something reappears after being deleted it most likely means your PC is infected with malware which Kaspersky doesn't detect.